# Installing PHP_7 localhost issue?

Tags: php

Im fed up at this stage with PHP. I have followed the tutorials on how to install it. I have done everything I am supposed to do with PHP.ini and httpd-conf file. 
I have apache running, PHP is installed as I verified it. Below is my example code Simple code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php echo "My first PHP script!"; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Instead of openeing in the browser as Localhost it is opening from **file:///C:/PHP/index.php**

I have set ServerName to **ServerName http://localhost:8080**

I am missing something but what I do not know.

Comment: That has nothing to do with PHP; that has to do with how you're trying to open it. It sounds like you're double-clicking or something. That won't work. Instead, you need to browse to `http://localhost:8080/index.php`, assuming you have set up a web server correctly and pointed it to the right directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using MAMP (free): https://www.mamp.info/en/

That will get you up and running with PHP in no-time, which is much more fun than server config.

And on a rainy day you can go back to the Apache-configurations :)